# Soundcloud http-error 401 Client Error Python

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, soundcloud, http-error

I am making a project for a client using soundcloud-python API. I am attempting to use the following line of code:

`client = soundcloud.Client(client_id="xxx", client_secret="xxx", username="xxx", password="xxx")` (Found on the soundcloud website https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs)

When I do so using the correct credentials I get:

`requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token`

Does anyone know how or why this is happening? I have double and triple checked my credentials, and they are the correct ones. I have been stuck on this for hours.

Thanks!

Comment: Having the same issue as well. Does it sometimes work for you and other times not? Soundcloud seems to rate-limit the password credentials grant after 10 requests in a short time.